# duplicate only the first row for each value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, row

I have the following dataframe:

```
fake = pd.DataFrame({"group" : ["A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C"], 
                     "num" : ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']})

>>> A   num
0   A   1
1   A   2
2   A   3
3   B   4
4   B   5
5   B   6
6   B   7
7   B   8
8   C   9
9   C   10
```

I would like for each group to get the first row only copied, t oget something like this:

```
>>> A   num
0   A   1
1   A   2
2   A   3
  **A   1**
3   B   4
4   B   5
5   B   6
6   B   7
7   B   8
  **B   4**
8   C   9
9   C   10
  **C   9**
```

When the stars are the new rows I would like to have (copy of the first one only)

how can I do something like this? I thought needs some kind of conditional duplicate but didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on column `group` and aggregate using `first` then use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concat it with the oringinal dataframe and finally `sort_values`:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df.groupby('group', as_index=False).first()])\
              .sort_values('group', ignore_index=True)
```

Result:

```
   group num
0      A   1
1      A   2
2      A   3
3      A   1
4      B   4
5      B   5
6      B   6
7      B   7
8      B   8
9      B   4
10     C   9
11     C  10
12     C   9
```

Answer (score 1):

One idea is use lambda function with [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
df = fake.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.append(x.iloc[0])).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   group num
0      A   1
1      A   2
2      A   3
3      A   1
4      B   4
5      B   5
6      B   6
7      B   7
8      B   8
9      B   4
10     C   9
11     C  10
12     C   9
```

Or you can use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for first rows, change index by last duplcates, add to original by [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) and last sorting index values for correct positions:

```
idx = fake.drop_duplicates('group', keep='last').index
df = (fake.append(fake.drop_duplicates('group')
                      .set_index(idx))
          .sort_index(kind='mergesort')
          .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
   group num
0      A   1
1      A   2
2      A   3
3      A   1
4      B   4
5      B   5
6      B   6
7      B   7
8      B   8
9      B   4
10     C   9
11     C  10
12     C   9
```